# Подправить код, который распространяется под лицензией MIT

Tags: лицензирование

Здравствуйте. Возможно я уже слишком заморачиваюсь, но все же. Есть модуль для node.js, который распространяется под [такой](https://github.com/acornejo/jjv/blob/master/LICENSE) лицензией (сверху написано *"The MIT License"*). У меня есть непреодолимое желание внести в код небольшое изменение (адаптировать для своих нужд). Вопрос - требуется ли от меня просить разрешение от автора, сообщать ему о том, что я изменил, или еще что-то?

Comment: Лицензия MIT это практически "делай что хочешь".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В лицензии черным по белому сказано, что вы имеете неограниченные права по ряду пунктов, в том числе и на изменение программного продукта. Тем самым автор уже дал вам свое согласие на изменение продукта, без каких-либо дополнительных условий. Можете свободно затачивать под свои нужды без всякий опасений.

---

UPD

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), в данном случае, я имел ввиду только само программное обеспечение. Конечно, требование предоставлять с продуктом копирайты и текст лицензии никуда не деваются. Однако никаких разрешений или указаний на измененные части проекта совершенно не требуются.

Но если хочется порядка, то можно создать в проекте файл licenses.txt и указать в нем, что

> В данном продукте используется %название% программное обеспечение под следующей MIT лицензией:
>
> %копирайты и текст лицензии%.

А так же создать файл readme.txt, в котором уже подробно указать, что и как для данного продукта было изменено в используемом. Ну или придумать свой вариант по душе. Однако, по лицензии MIT, это совершенно не обязательно и достаточно только текста с копирайтами.

Можно даже сделать закрытое проприетарное ПО на основе MIT и продавать его, в этой лицензии главное передача прав на полное использование с сохранением авторства и отказ от дальнейшей ответственности.

Comment: Наверное менять можно не совсем все. 

Исходный копирайт и сама лицензия на дальнейшие изменения кем угодно должны остаться.

Comment: Уже после написания вопроса на хабре появилась неплохая статья, вкратце описывающая различные open source лицензии. Оставлю ссылку тут, вдруг пригодится:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/243091/

Answer (score 2):

[Текст](https://github.com/acornejo/jjv/blob/fa2ed4f0f6023a58e0b93902d9f26547ad1b046b/LICENSE) соответствует [The MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), так что можно изменять не спрашивая автора и не сообщая ему об изменениях (но нельзя лицензию удалять с копирайтом автора, она обязана присутствовать во всех копиях).

Comment: @jfs, а такой умозрительный вопрос.

Допустим я поменял полфайла кода. Наверное я должен оставить ту же лицензию и куда-то дописать, что я в коде менял.

Вот как это надо оформлять? 
(я имею в виду сам текст в файле)

Comment: @avp: да, нужно оставить (пол-файла -- существенная часть старого кода). Нет, не нужно дописывать. Могут быть лицензии, которые этого требуют, но не MIT/Expat. Вот [сайт от гитхаба, который может помочь в выборе лицензии, где кратко без легалайза описано, что можно, что нельзя](http://choosealicense.com/).

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, прочел. В очередной раз обратил внимание на то, что отсутсвие какой-либо лицензии существенно ограничивает возможности остальных программеров (*законопослушных*) в использовании кода.

--

А если я хочу дописать что новые полфайла-то уже мои, то где это надо делать?

Просто в новом  комментарии под оригинальным текстом лицензии с копирайтом первого автора или где-то еще?  
(допустим, что мне совершенно не хочется плодить еще какие-то файлы)

Comment: @avp: система контроля версий помнит: кто, что, когда менял. Если хочется увековечить себя прямо в файле, то тоже можно. Лицензия даже разрешает распространять изменения по более ограничивающей лицензии. А выше/ниже комментарии помещать -- я не знаю: что важнее для будущего читателя: по какой лицензии код распространяется или какие изменения были сделаны по сравнению с версией изначального автора?

Comment: @jfs, понятно, что я не имел в виду совместную разработку, управление версиями и т.п.

Я имел в виду ситуацию, когда человек просто скачал файлик. Поправил-дополнил. Выложил куда-то в другое место (или просто отдал кому-нибудь). И никаких git, svn и т.д.

Вот я про какие варианты.

--

В принципе же, лично я вообще не сторонник всей этой бюрократии с лицензиями и правами. Написал (если дописал, тогда поставь ссылку на источник и отметь свои правки комментариями по ходу кода) -- отдай другим. Главное, чтобы никто не прерывал своими поправками этот процесс.