# Использование фреймворка Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Будет ли нарушение авторских прав за использование фреймворка Bootstrap? И можно ли редактировать исходный код Bootstrap?

Comment: Сорри за вероятно глупый вопрос, но что означает "АП" в данном контексте? Исходники бутстрапа редактировать - можно, да (лицензия у них указана MIT, она это позволяет).

Comment: Не может быть авторского права?

Comment: Авторское право и может быть, и есть  Ну а если вопрос подразумевался о нарушении авторских прав, то таким нарушением является например объявление себя автором чужого произведения... это совсем не то же самое, что создание производного произведения (забавный термин), коим является форк проекта с разрешенным, легальным изменением исходников. Короче, авторские права на бутстрап - остаются у его авторов; ты получаешь авторские права на свои изменения исходников бутстрапа, в момент создания измененной копии (если находишься в РФ, где авторское право приобретается автоматически).

Comment: Введи «лицензия MIT» в поиск (в верхней части этой страницы) - найдешь доп. информацию, которая может быть полезна... И кстати, настоятельно рекомендуется использовать поиск _до_ того как задавать вопрос.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подправить код, который распространяется под лицензией MIT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373031/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b7%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-mit)